# Function which detects rotations

Tags: functions, finite-groups, permutations

Consider a function $F: \mathbb{F}_2^d \to \mathbb{Z}^n = (f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ with the property that if $y \in \mathbb{F}_2^d$ is a rotation of $x \in \mathbb{F}_2^d$, i.e. $y$ is $x$ permuted by an element of the cyclic group generated by $(1 \ 2 \ldots d)$, then F(x)=F(y), and the additional constraint that $f_i$ is of the form

$
f_i(x) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^d \alpha_jx_j
$.

There are obvious examples of such functions, for instance $F(x) = \sum\limits_{1}^d x_i$. For any $x \in \mathbb{F}_2^d$ and $\pi \in S_d$, $F(x)=F(\pi x)$. We say that such a function is fixed under $S_d$. However, as you might expect from my initial explanation, I am interested in such a function which is fixed strictly under rotations, that is for any permutation $\pi$ which is not a rotation, then $F(x) \neq F(\pi x)$, or at least fixed under rotations and not fixed under all of $S_d$.

Do such functions exist? I am having difficulty finding any example which is not the one I gave above.

EDIT: Such functions do not exist courtesy of the answer below, but what about letting our domain be a strict subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_2^d$? Specifically one not containing the vectors $e_i$?

Comment: If we disregard the requirement that $f_i$ must be of the form $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^d\alpha_jx_j$ then we can produce things like $x_1x_2^2x_3^3 + x_1^2x_2^3x_3 + x_1^3x_2x_3^2$. This is fixed under rotations in $S_3$, but not under all of $S_3$ (for example switching $x_1$ and $x_2$ leads to a different expression). I have trouble writing this down in general form for some reason.

Comment: Are these terms not all the same given $x_i \in F_2^d$?

Comment: Ah you are right I was thinking of abstract polynomials rather than functions from $\mathbb{F}_2^d$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Slightly revised now that the question's confusion of $n$ and $d$ has been resolved)

That's the only one (up to constant multiples).

Why? Because $f( (1,0,..., 0)) = f( (0, 1, ...0)$ (since the second argument is the result of rotating the first, and $f$ is supposed to be invariant under rotations). This implies that  $a_1 = a_2$. Similarly, $a_2 = a_3$, and so on.

A slightly more sophisticated view: You have a group $G$ (in this case, integers mod $d$) acting on your domain $\Bbb F_2^d$, which I'll call just $D$ for "domain". So for every $g \in G$ and $x \in D$, you have $gx \in D$, with nice properties like $(g_1g_2)x = g_1 (g_2 x)$, etc.

You'd like to find a function $f$ invariant under $g$, so that $f(gx) = x$ for every $x$.

When $G$ is finite (and somewhat more general as well, but with some conditions I'm not going to write out here), *summing* or *averaging* does the trick. Given some function $h: D \to H$ (where $H$ is a set rich enough to have a notion of sums, and to allow division by the size of $G$), you can define
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} h(gx).
$$

If it happens that $h$ is already $G$-invariant, then this makes $f(x)$ be just $h(x)$, i.e., the operation above ends up leaving $G$-invariant functions unchanged. But if $h$ is any other function, then the resulting $f$ will be $G$-invariant. In other words, I've shown you a function from "all functions on $D$" to "$G$-invariant functions on $D$", and it's surjective.

In your case, if you simply look at each component of $F$, it's a $\Bbb Z/\Bbb dZ$-invariant integer-valued linear function. Starting from $h(x_1, \ldots, x_d) = x_1$, you get $f(x_1, \ldots, x_d) = \frac{1}{d}(x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_d)$.

Now the "division by $d$" is a problem here, but you don't have to do it. If you leave out the $\frac{1}{|G|}$, you get a map from "functions" to $G$-invariant functions, but it's not the identity on $G$-invariant ones, i.e., it's no longer a projection. But the main ideas remain.

This general notion is used to defining the Haar measure on a compact Lie Group, and in various other situations as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe the n was a mistake there, I have fixed it in the question above. You are clearly correct that only one of these functions exists up to scaling if our domain is all of $\mathbb{F}_2^d$, but what if our domain is a strict subgroup not containing the $e_i$?

Comment: I still see many $n$s and $d$s in the question. As for your second question...that's a very different question, and one on which I have no immediate insight. You should perhaps think about it for a while, and then consider posting it (carefully making sure you get all the $n$s and $d$s right. :)  ).

Comment: Ah the only $n$ should be on $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (our function can have any number of coordinates)--I see I left $S_n$ in by mistake I have fixed it. Thanks for your insight on this!

Comment: Revised to reflect the renaming.

Comment: Also: adding a modified question to the tail of your question is bad form. Go ahead and ask a new one, and let this one, which is at least a little interesting, stand on its own.